# Подход в написании регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Привет всем!

Какой на ваш взгляд подход в написании регулярного выражения более правильный? Если мне нужно например словить в строке

> 2016/10/14 08:28:17 [error] 30980#0: *104483032 limiting requests,
>   excess: 500.260 by zone "http", client: 44.111.22.11, server:
>   www.test.com, request: "GET
>   /public/compiled/responsive-styles-forms2-validation
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "www.test.com", referrer:
>   "http://www.test.com/"

ip адрес клиента. Правильнее, будет выглядеть регулярка вроде этой:

```
^.*limiting requests, excess: [\d\.]+ by zone "[^"]+", client: <HOST>
```

где HOST это группа которая парсит ip
или парсить всё что встречается? Например:

```
> \d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \[error\] \d+#\d+: \*\d+ limiting
> requests, excess: [\d\.]+ by zone "[^"]+", client: <HOST>
```

Ну и т.д. HOST - опять же группа парсящая ip.

Не знаю что значит "правильная" регулярка. Может та, которая приведёт к меньшей нагрузке на процессор.

Comment: Если после "client: " всегде идет IP и после него пробел - regexp не нужен

Comment: Но могут встречаться другие выражения, с client: 1.2.3.4 вызванные не превышением кол-ва запрсов. А мне нужны именно сообщения о превышении кол-ва запросов. Поправлю вопрос.

Comment: *Может та, которая приведёт к меньшей нагрузке на процессор* -- я очень сильно сомневаюсь в том, что узкое место вашего кода по производительности будет именно здесь... Во всяком случае до профилирования этого сказать нельзя, а заниматься оптимизацией не пойми чего и зачем, без явных на то показаний - пустая трата времени.

Comment: @MishaPolitaev: вы не рассматривали вариант создания дополнительной директивы error_log, которая писала бы только IP?

Comment: Идея классная, НО. Это nginx, а формат error лога в нём кажется не кастомизируется, а во-вторых это лишь одна из множества ошибок которые имеют поле client. Ошибка о том что upstream не ответил например тоже имеет поле client, которое мне ни к чему.

Comment: @MishaPolitaev в nginx всё отлично кастомизируется.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не нахожу этого в оф. документации. Про access_log - да. Можешь дать ссылку где ты это видел? Спасибо.

Comment: @MishaPolitaev помню, что вроде мы его кастомизировали. Постараюсь сегодня вечером найти либо маны, либо исходники (что не факт, работу сменил).

Comment: @MishaPolitaev вроде вспомнил: error_log кастомизировать может и нельзя, но можно сделать ещё один лог (или несколько) и писать туда только нужные события и в нужном формате. Т.е. проще заставить nginx дополнительно писать лог в удобном нам формате, чем научиться читать неудобный общий лог. Мы настраивали таким образом, чтобы каждая строка лога представляла из себя валидный json, вместо того чтобы парсить строку и собирать из нее json.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ок, спасибо.

Comment: @MishaPolitaev если найдёте решение — опубликуйте, с меня плюс. )

Answer (score 1):

Выделяйте как совпадение все после `client:` до запятой, но если этот текст не соответствует маске для корректного IP v4/v6, то делайте для этого сообщения предупреждение.
Когда увидите предупреждение, то внимательно изучите входной текст и определите самостоятельно- что привело к ложному срабатыванию.

Если важна производительность, то используйте такое регулярное выражение:

```
^(?:[^l]++|l)*?limiting requests, excess: [\d\.]+ by zone "[^"]+", client:\s*[^,]++
```

Comment: Мне ничего не нужно искать после client. Зачем его выделять? И проверку эту делать тоже не нужно. Мне только интересно есть ли вероятность что я пропущу client поле если использую 1-й вариант вместо 2-го как у меня в вопросе.

Comment: Вы спросили про подход: я описал его Вам. Да. Вы можете пропустить, если будете использовать первый вариант. Замените максимальную квантификацию минимальной, чтобы избежать этого. Собственно я сделал это в своем примере регулярного выражения.

Comment: Благодарю за описанный вами подход, пригодится!
А в каких случаях при максимальной квантификации можно пропустить? Просто сейчас не пропускается. 
И ещё, что значит (?:[^l]++|l)*? из вашего вариант? Почему не просто .*?

Comment: Это оптимизация минимальной квантификации, чтобы меньше точек возврата создавать. Пример: `...... referrer: "limiting requests, excess: 1 by zone ".", client: 1.1.1.1 "`

Comment: Все-равно не понятно, но спасибо, сам попытаюсь разобраться)

Comment: Дык что тут непонятного: в рефферер можно написать что угодно и если этот текст совпадет с шаблоном, то будет выбран он.

Comment: Но referrer идёт же после client. Он не учитывается.

Comment: Учитывается. Читайте как работает максимальная квантификация.